# Adding a TFS server group to access levels via command line

Tags: tfs-security

I am creating a group of users within TFS 2013 and I want to add them to the none default access level (ex. the full access group) but I noticed I am only able to do this through the web interface by adding a TFS Group under that certain level. I am wondering if there is a way to do this via the developer tool (command line) as everything I am doing is being done in a batch script.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 TFS server groups; add these groups to the different access levels (e.g. `TFS_ACCESS_LEVEL_(NONE|STANDARD|FULL)`). Now use the TFSSecurity commandline tool to add groups to these existing and mapped groups(`tfssecurity /g+ TFS_ACCESS_LEVEL_NONE GroupYouWantToHaveThisAccessLevel`). There is no other way to directly add people to the access levels, except probably through the Object Model using C#.

Comment: This is the solution I have in my system with the additional step that I manage membership via an additional Active Directory group.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, `tfssecurity` may require the URI, which can be obtained via API. This is easy to do in Powershell, here is how to create a TFS group

```
[psobject] $tfs = get-tfs -serverName $collection
$projectUri = ($tfs.CSS.ListAllProjects() | where { $_.Name -eq $project }).Uri
& $TFSSecurity /gc $projectUri $groupName $groupDescription /collection:$collection
```

Full script at [TfsSecurity wrapper](http://blog.casavian.eu/blog/2014/11/06/tfssecurity/).